# Pausar una iteración del ciclo while en Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

Quiero detener mi ciclo while por unos segundos y que despues siga siguiente iteración.

Este es mi código:

```
while(GameP.getStatus()===GAME_STATUS.PLAYING){
    console.log("Ciclo de juego");
    GameP.moveBall(); //Movemos la bola

    GameP.checkCollision();//Chequeamos si hay una colision
    GameP.checkScore(); //Chequeamos la puntuación
    
    //Establecemos una pausa de 1 segundo;

    //Enviamos el estado del juego a los clientes
}
```

Probé algo por así:

```
export async function init() {
    console.log("Antes del segundo")
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log("Despues del segundo")
}
  
function sleep(ms:number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Pero el ciclo while se sigue ejecutando.

Supongo que podría poner el cuerpo del while en una función y con `setTimeout()` invocarla cada X tiempo.

Pero a lo que quiero llegar es saber si existe alguna forma de PAUSAR la ejecución del código y después siga como si nada.

---

Actualización.

El problema lo pude resolver con el siguiente código.

```
//Cada 1 segundo, se ejecuta un ciclo del juego y se emite al cliente
    setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Ciclo del juego")
            GameP.cicleOfGame();
        }, 1000);
```

Lo que me sigue generando dudas es la pregunta inicial:

> "existe alguna forma de PAUSAR la ejecución del código y después siga
> como si nada"

Answer (score 3):

En tu codigo anterior, no veo porque la promesa deberia causar una pausa, la funcion que manda a llamar a la promesa a resolver en sleep se dispara y no tiene porque esperar a que se resuelva, pero si ejecutas init de manera que si devuelva una promesa entonces si puedes poner la funcion sleep y "pausar" o retrasar la resolucion de la promesa, asi:

```javascript
async function init () {
    console.log('inicia');
    await sleep(1000);  
  console.log('finaliza');
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return function(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), ms));
  };
}

// Llamando a init directamente
init();

// Resolviendo init como promesa
let res = init();

res
.then(sleep(1000))
.then (res => {
  console.log('promesa resuelta despues de un segundo');
})
```